# Почему не сдвигается окно Qt, C++?

Tags: c++, qt

У меня у окне есть кнопка, которая при событии mouseMove становится новым окном. Но когда она становится новым окном, это окно позиционируется в левый верхний угол(координаты 0, 0) экрана. И это происходит, даже если я пишу `move();` или `setGeometry();`. При этом, кнопку потом можно нормально двигать курсором мыши(при помощи события, которое я описал). Почему так происходит? Вот код:

```
class QPushButtonn: public QPushButton{
    public:
    QPushButtonn(QWidget * parent = nullptr):QPushButton(parent){}
    QPoint Position;
    virtual void QPushButtonn::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* pe)
    {
        Position = pe->globalPos()-this->pos();
    }
    virtual void QPushButtonn::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* pe)
    {
        if(this->parent()!=nullptr){
            this->setParent(nullptr);
            move(350,350); //либо так this->setGeometry(1000,1000, 350,350);
            this->show();
        }
        move(pe->globalPos() - Position);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QMainWindow *window = new QMainWindow();
    window->resize(336, 227);
    window->show();
    QPushButtonn bbbtn(window);
    bbbtn.resize(100, 100);
    bbbtn.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: А что происходит, когда Вы используете setGeometry ?

Comment: @isnullxbh окно появляется, заданного размера, но в точке 0, 0

Comment: можно сам код увидеть с setGeometry ?

Comment: @isnullxbh, добавил в код.

Comment: Какое у Вас разрешение экрана ?

Comment: @isnullxbh дело не в разрешении. Если просто отдельно создать какой либо элемент, и сдвинуть его через `move` или `setGeometry`, то он будет прекрасно двигаться хоть за пределы экрана, я проверял.

Comment: Может это и глупо, но у меня была такая проблема под GTK - я задал минимальный размер окна - и все заработало )

Comment: @isnullxbh в данном случае, как подсказал @Unick, проблема была в строке `move(pe->globalPos() - Position);`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по всему вызов функции move(pe->globalPos() - Position); перемещает окно в (0, 0), т.к. Position равна pe->globalPos(). Вы можете переписать метод вот так:

```
virtual void QPushButtonn::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* pe)
{
    if (this->parent() != nullptr) {
        QPoint globPos = this->mapToGlobal(this->pos());
        this->setParent(nullptr);
        move(globPos); //либо так this->setGeometry(1000,1000, 350,350);
        this->show();
    }
    else
    {
        move(pe->globalPos() - Position);
    }
}
```

В этом случае окно будет расположено там же где и кнопа. Но Drag&Drop не будет не удобен, т.к. когда кнопа становится окном и она не получает сообщения в передвижении мыши. Тут необходимо или устанавливать фокус или настроить трекинг курсора мыши. Но это по видимому другая проблема.

Comment: Да, все работает, только так окно создается с небольшим сдвигом, чтобы исправить его нужны такие строки: `QPoint p = this->parentWidget()->pos();` и изменить вашу `move(globPos-(globPos-p));`. Теперь всё создается хорошо, но когда создается окно нужно по нему нажать еще раз, чтобы его можно было тянуть. Как можно с этим бороться, чтобы тянуть за один раз?

Comment: Лучше создайте отдельный вопрос на эту проблему, так у вас больше шансов получить ответ. Я думаю окно просто не получает фокус и поэтому не получает события мыши. Нужно программного сделать окно или кнопу на этом окне активным.